# Why do I get this error in R: "Error in library(packlist[i]) : 'package' must be of length 1"?

Tags: r, function, error-handling, package

I am trying to write a function that takes in package names as arguments, and then checks whether they are installed or not one at a time. If they are not installed, then the function will install the packages and subsequently load them into the current session. If they are installed, then the function will just load the packages into the current session.

```
packin <- function(...) {
  packlist <- list(...)
  for(i in 1:length(packlist)) {
    if(!requireNamespace(packlist[i])) {
    install.packages(packlist[i])
    library(packlist[i])
      } else {
        library(packlist[i])
        }
  }
}
```

I tried this with two packages: tidyverse (installed but not loaded) and writexl (neither installed nor loaded).

```
packin('tidyverse', 'writexl')
```

But this produces the error: `Error in library(packlist[i]) : 'package' must be of length 1`. However, when I check the length of a list of both packages for one item in the list, the length is equal to 1.

```
packlist <- list('tidyverse', 'writexl')
length(packlist[1]) == 1
```

`length(packlist[1]) == 1` returns `TRUE`. So what am I doing wrong or not understanding about the error that the 'package' must be of length 1 when it is telling me that is of length 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `character.only = TRUE` when passing anything other than a literal string to `library():

```r
p <- list("writexl", "tidyverse")
library(p[1])  ## Error in library(p) : there is no package called ‘p’
library(p[1], character.only = TRUE)
```

The reason for the obscure error message is that `library()` internally calls:

```r
if (!character.only) package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

which evaluates (weirdly) to `"[" "p" "1"` in this case (or `"[" "packlist" "i"` if the input is `packlist[i]`)

You can probably do this slightly more compactly:

```r
packin <- function(...) {
  packlist <- unlist(list(...))
  ip <- rownames(installed.packages())
  to_install <- setdiff(packlist, ip)
  install.packages(to_install, character.only = TRUE)
  sapply(packlist, library, character.only = TRUE)
}
```

The `pacman` package has a lot of useful functions for this kind of thing.

Comment: Those do the trick, thank you! And yes, I saw that the `pacman` package has a function that does exactly what I am wanting `p_load()`. I am just curious why you have to use `character.only = TRUE` when `class(packlist[[1]])` is of the character class?

Comment: Because `library()` does clever non-standard evaluation stuff: unless told `character.only = TRUE`, it tries to turn the symbol passed to the function back into a string (i.e. the user can specify either `library(mypkg)` or `library("mypkg")`)

Answer (score 1):

The code below creates the function that solves my problem thanks to @BenBolker's answer:

```
packin <- function(...) {
  packs <- list(...)
  for(i in 1:length(packs)) {
    if(!requireNamespace(packs[[i]])) {
      install.packages(packs[[i]])
      library(packs[[i]], character.only = TRUE)
    } else {
    library(packs[[i]], character.only = TRUE)
    }
  }
}
```